# javascript download file from path

Tags: javascript, html, laravel, file, download

Below is the example i've used to download files but it only opens file in the next tab. it does not downloads files.

```
function download(items) {
 
  items.forEach(function (item, index) {
   // console.log(item);
    var anchor = document.createElement('a');
    anchor.href = item.url;
    anchor.target = '_blank';
    anchor.download = item.name;
    anchor.innerHTML ='download';
    setTimeout(function () {
    //  console.log(anchor);
      anchor.click();      
    }, index * 100);
  });
}
```

Comment: Can you share what `item.url` and `item.name` looks like?

Comment: Welcome to SO ...what url is generated ? can you put that

Comment: name: "dummy.pdf", 
url: "https://fixe-dev-account-files.s3-us-east-2.amazonaws.com/files/files/Account 1/dummy.pdf",

Answer (score 0):

```
fetch("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a3/June_odd-eyed-cat.jpg")
    .then(response => response.blob())
    .then(blob => {

        const blobURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        const a = document.createElement("a");
        a.href = blobURL;
        a.innerHTML = "download"
        a.setAttribute('download', 'true')
        document.body.appendChild(a);

    })
```

The download attribute only works for same origin URLs

This API call takes a URL and creates a downloadable image

Comment: i am getting 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' error now